# PHP/MySQL Form Input - Quiz Game

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

I am creating a website which users can register for membership - once registered, the user can view the index.php page which contains a form:

Index.php

```
 <?php # index.php
 session_start();
 //check session first
 if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
 include ('../includes/header.php');
 }else
     {
 session_start();
 include ('../includes/header.php');
 require_once ('../../mysql_connect.php');
          $query = "SELECT * FROM answers ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; 
          $result = @mysql_query ($query);
          $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
          if ($num > 0) { // If it ran OK, display all the records.
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {      
 ?>

 <div class="newGame">
       <h2>Are you a Question Master?<hr /></h2>
       <h3 style="color:#000">Find Out Now!</h3>
 </div>
 <br />

 <div class="newGameContain">
       <form action="gameSubmit.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
       <h2><? echo $row["Question"]."<hr />"; ?></h2>
       <h3>Enter Player Answers</h3>
              <p><input type="text" placeholder="Player 1" name="player1" value="<? echo $_POST['player1']; ?>" /> <input type="text" placeholder="Player 2" name="player2" value="<? echo $_POST['player2']; ?>" /></p>
              <p><input type="text" placeholder="Player 3" name="player3" value="<? echo $_POST['player3']; ?>" /> <input type="text" placeholder="Player 4" name="player4" value="<? echo $_POST['player4']; ?>" /></p>
              <p><input type="submit" class="submitButton" /> <input type="reset" class="resetButton" value="Reset" /> </p>
              <input type="hidden" name="questionId" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" />
              <input type="hidden" name"qAnswer" value="<?php echo $row["Answer"]; ?>" />
              <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
 </form>
 <p></p>
 </div>
 <br />


 <?php
                   } //end while statement
          } //end if statement
     mysql_close();
     //include the footer
     include ("../includes/footer.php");
 }
 ?>
```

Then on the form action page (gameSubmit.php) I have the following code:

gameSubmit.php

```
 <?php # index.php
 session_start();
 //check session first
 if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])){
 include ('../includes/header.php');
 }else
     {
 session_start();
 include ('../includes/header.php');
 require_once ('../../mysql_connect.php');
          $query = "SELECT * FROM answers ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"; 
          $result = @mysql_query ($query);
          $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
               if ($num > 0) { // If it ran OK, display all the records.
                  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {      
 ?>

 <? if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
      $correct1Msg = "<div class='correct1Msg'><p style='color:#000;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>Player 1 entered the <span id='answerUnder'>correct answer</span>.</p></div><p></p>";
      $correct2Msg = "<div class='correct2Msg'><p style='color:#000;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>Player 2 entered the <span id='answerUnder'>correct answer</span>.</p></div><p></p>";
      $incorrect1Msg = "<div class='incorrect1Msg'><p style='color:#F00;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>Player 1 entered the <span id='answerUnder'>incorrect answer</span>.</p></div><p></p>";
      $incorrect2Msg = "<div class='incorrect2Msg'><p style='color:#F00;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;'>Player 2 entered the <span id='answerUnder'>incorrect answer</span>.</p></div><p></p>";

 $player1Answer = $_POST['player1'];
 $player2Answer = $_POST['player2'];
 $player3Answer = $_POST['player3'];
 $player4Answer = $_POST['player4'];

 $correctAnswer = $row['Answer'];
 $questionAnswer = $_POST['qAnswer'];
 $questionID = $row['ID'];
 $answeredID = $_POST['questionId'];
 $id1 = 1;
 $id2 = 2;
 $answer1 = "Red";
 $answer2 = "4";

         if ($player1Answer == $questionAnswer){
             echo $correct1Msg;
         }

         if ($player1Answer != $questionAnswer){
             echo $incorrect1Msg;
         }

         if ($questionID == "1" && $player2Answer == "Red"){
             echo $correct2Msg;
         }elseif ($questionID == "2" && $player2Answer == "4"){
             echo $correct2Msg;
         }else{
             echo $incorrect2Msg;
         }

         if ($questionID == "1" && $player3Answer == "Red"){
             echo $correct3Msg;
         }elseif ($questionID == "2" && $player3Answer == "4"){
             echo $correct3Msg;
         }else{
             echo $incorrect3Msg;
         }

         if ($questionID == "1" && $player4Answer == "Red"){
             echo $correct4Msg;
         }elseif ($questionID == "2" && $player4Answer == "4"){
             echo $correct4Msg;
         }else{
             echo $incorrect4Msg;
         }
 }
 ?>

 <?php
                   } //end while statement
          } //end if statement
     mysql_close();
     //include the footer
     include ("../includes/footer.php");
 }
 ?>
```

So as you can see, I'm attempting a few different methods of verifying the players answer with the last question. Basically, I am trying to make it so that when the user submits the initial form (located on index.php) - the form action (gameSubmit.php) will check each player answer with the correct answer from the question displayed on the last page (i.e. the question the players responded to) - I have tirelessly scoured the forums, websites, books and more for an answer to my problem; I just can't seem to find an explanation I understand or that works for me.

Comment: Mike B - I apologize, how do I take the user answers and on form submit check if they inputted the correct answer on the gameSubmit.php page? Sorry, its difficult for me to word. Currently, my method of validation isn't consistent it doesn't cross-reference the question/answer that the players answered - it is completely random.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` is a double error. 1. never use `mysql_num_rows` unless you are trying to get the *actual row count*. Use `_fetch_row` directly and test for null. 2. Don't use `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Also, there is a live preview of the website at http://kethcart.uwmsois.com/qm/htdocs/Home/index.php - you will have to register an account but you will find the game form on the homepage (index.php) feel free to test it out.

Comment: `input type="hidden" name"qAnswer" value="<?php echo $row["Answer"]; ?>"` You know this isn't hidden from users right? ie in very quick and simple ways they can get the answer.

Comment: cwallenpoole - I understand this isn't the correct format, I realized that when I was searching for an answer; I also realize the ORDER BY RAND() method is technically a poor option, however, this is a school assignment and it must be completed in this manner - or as close as possible to it.

Comment: James - Yes, I understand it is not hidden; to be honest, I could care less if a user wants to cheat and find the answer - I just want to be able to check that the user input with the correct answer on the form action page. It's not a big deal if the site is secure/displays answers in the code, I just need it to function as a consistent form/form action.

Comment: I figured it out because of James haha - if you look in my code, I was calling the hidden input qAnswer but it was missing an '=' sign so it wasn't passing the value.

Comment: It would be good practice for you to check the answer using your query on your action page. Plus, it would eliminate the possibility of cheating, which can never be a bad thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action page is grabbing a new random question.

You need to do something like:

```
$qid = $_POST["questionId"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE questionId='$qid'";
```

I would recommend:

- use `mysqli_` functions
- avoid `SELECT *` - instead, specify the columns you require
- escape user inputs before putting them in a MySQL query, such as `mysqli_escape_string`

Comment: rybo111 - Thank you very much for the answer, I am applying the changes now and will let you know how it works.